# How can two branches be combined into a single branch based on the date of each commit?

Tags: git, date, merge, rebase, cherry-pick

Let's say I have a git repository that looks like this:

```
merge-base---A1--A2------A3------A4 (branchA)
          \
           ----------B1------B2 (branchB)
```

To make things simpler, let's say the commits on branchA are strictly modifications to fileA, and the commits on branchB are strictly modifications to fileB.

I want to combine these branches into a third branch, branchAB, where the commits will be ordered by date:

```
merge-base---A1--A2------A3------A4 (branchA)
          \
           ----------B1------B2 (branchB)
            \
             A1--A2--B1--A3--B2--A4 (branchAB)
```

Is there a way to automatically do this with a single git command, or am I stuck with manual methods (e.g. cherry picking or rebase -i)?

BTW, `merge-base` is a tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution that does what I want, based on [adymitruk's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410742/how-can-two-branches-be-combined-into-a-single-branch-based-on-the-date-of-each-c/5411058#5411058):

```
git checkout -b branchAB merge-base
git merge branchA
git merge branchB
git rebase --onto merge-base merge-base branchAB
```

Comment: I know the first merge is a fast-forward only. So why not just create the ab branch on top of one of the other branches as a starting point?

Comment: @adymitruk: Won't that re-order the commits so that you get all of one branch's commits followed by all of the other branch's commits? It's very important that the order (based on date) be preserved.

Comment: @adymitruk: Thinking about it a bit more, yes it should be fine to start branchAB at the tip of branchA, then merge-in branchB. The important thing is to do a `rebase --onto` to remove the merge history on branchAB, reordering the commits by date.

Comment: If work continues on both branchA and branchB after this merging step, will this procedure also continue to work?  Or does the rebase screw that up?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
git branch branchAB branchA
git checkout branchB
git merge branchA
git rebase --onto A1^ B1^ branchAB
```

The rebase will "eat" the merge commit as --preserve-merges was not specified.

hope this helps

Comment: Close, but there are two problems with your solution. First, rather than creating a third branch, branchAB, it modifies branchB. Second, the last command deletes A4 from the combined branch (branchB). Other than those two things, it does exactly what I want. Thanks! If you can fix the two issues I mentioned, I'll mark your answer as accepted ;)

Comment: done. No need to do a fast-forward merge, just create the AB branch on top of one of the others.

Comment: I just tried your edited solution (substituting `A1^` and `B1^` with `merge-base`). Unfortunately, it doesn't even come close to working. `branchAB` ends up the same as `branchA`, and `branchB` gets altered to point to *Merge branch 'branchA' into branchB*.

Comment: To clarify, by "your edited solution" I meant revision 3 of your answer. Revision 1 was closer.

Comment: git rebase --onto branchB branchA branchAB