# Is there a way to merge two local branches together in Intellij

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have checked out a branch from remote->develop twice with names dev and develop. These dev and develop are my local branches. I have made changes in both. Now i need to merge them both as a single local branch so that both changes are present in a single branch. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can two branches be combined into a single branch based on the date of each commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410742/how-can-two-branches-be-combined-into-a-single-branch-based-on-the-date-of-each)

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

1. Be sure to be in the master branch
2. `Version Control` tab
3. Double-click on the last commit
4. Hover the option "Branch 'branch-name'"
5. Click on "Merge into current"

You can follow the following commands if you want to use the commands.

`git checkout master`
Switched to branch "master"

`git merge dev`
To merge the new feature in the "dev" branch into the "master" branch

`git merge develop`
To merge the new feature in the "develop" branch into the "master" branch

At the end, the branch "master" will contain all the features in both "dev" and "develop" branches.

Be aware that conflicts may occur.

Comment: thanks for those insights. But i need to merge dev with develop or develop with dev. Is there any ways to do that?